# Is there a way to create a PowerBI slicer (single select) for a sub-group only?

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a single select Slicer in PowerBI that displays the following:

#### GROUP A

- SUB A
- SUB B
- SUB C

#### GROUP B

- SUB A
- SUB B

e.g.

[image]

But I would like the user only to be able to select a single selected option for any of the  SUB groups only and not the GROUP.

When I turn on the single select option for the slicer, GROUPs are also available to select from, which is not what I would like.

For clarity, I would like the GROUP to be a heading only and the SUB options to be selectable.

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean if someone selects a sub from group A, group B should be disabled with all subs deselected?

Comment: I mean that only child elements are selectable and not the parent.  If any Sub is selected within a parent group, all other subs are disabled.

Comment: Sorry, I can not visualize your requirement.

Comment: Just for everyone else's benefit, I just found this: Hierarchy Slicer that does do what I need.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380820?exp=ubp8

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's your need. it's in single selection of Sub. visual is basic visual of slicer.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  However, In this example, if I select Category01, all the Products are also selected underneath. I want the option only to allow Products to be selectable and no Category (in your example).  As noted above, I did end up finding a custom visual that supports the feature I wanted.

Comment: oh i see your comment above. sure then it all down. 